# How do i convert a jqueryui theme to Asp.net Theme

Tags: asp.net, css, jquery-ui, themeroller, app-themes

Just got puzzled and lost on this, i downloaded the jQueryUI Cupertino theme for a personal project. I do know how to use it when on single page, but just got stumped on how to convert the theme to a asp.net theme for use with masterpage, This is all i did but in vain,

1. Downloaded the Theme from the theme base
2. Created a App_Theme directory in the Project
3. Created a Cupertino theme folder inside the above directory
4. Copied all the css and images directory in the Cupertino theme downloaded
5. Set the Page.Theme to Cupertino , and Nothing happens :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Theme being set in MasterPage had been overridden in child page causing the confusion, removed the code that set's the theme in child page now works great.

Answer (score 0):

check in web.config , in pages section you declare default theme as "Cupertino " or not.

Comment: what difference does it make defining the Theme in `web.config` and the `Page_PreInit` event

Comment: when you set in web.config it does not need to set in every page and in master page it automatically set and by default use you default theme which is declared in web.config

Comment: doesn't quite answer my question, please do follow the steps i outlined and try a quick look at the test webpage, the theme doesn't get applied

Comment: i create one theme "DefaultTheme" in app_theme ( with css and skin file) 2. i send that theme in web.config <pages theme="DefaultTheme"> 3. i add css in master page " <link href="css/ss_techno.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />" 4. i create one child page called home.aspx its work fine.

Comment: can you send master page source ?

Comment: the problem seemed to be something else, the theme got overridden even though i set it,from another page